# Cannot pass SelectedValue and Text to Controller for a KendoUIDropDownListFor widget

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, telerik-mvc

This works fine if I don't use any KendoUI functionality and am able to pass it easily using a regular Html.DropDownListfor helper (seen as comments in the code). The Description and the StatusID both do not come through.

How can I pass these values to the controller after selecting them in the dropdown list and then clicking enter with the KendoUI extension?

If I uncomment the Value and Text properties, I get "Object not set to an instance of an Object".

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddSingleStatus", "Status", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="display-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Description);
                </div>
                <div class="display-label" style="display: none;">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Description)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => Model.StatusID)
                        .Name("statusDropDownList") 
                        .DataTextField("Description") 
                        .DataValueField("StatusID") 
                            .DataSource(source =>
                            {
                                source.Read(read =>
                                {
                                    read.Action("ReadDDL", "Status"); 
                                })
                                   .ServerFiltering(false); 
                            })
                        .OptionLabel("Select a status")
                        .SelectedIndex(0) 
                        .Events(e => e
                             .Change("dropdownlist_change")
                        )
                    )

                    @* @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.StatusID, new SelectList((YeagerTechModel.Status[])ViewData["statuses"], "StatusID", "Description"));*@
                    @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.StatusID)*@
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" id="ddlSubmit" value='@Resources.Add' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function dropdownlist_change()
    {
        var dropdownlist = $("#statusDropDownList").data("kendoDropDownList");

        dropdownlist.bind("change", function (e)
        {
            var value = dropdownlist.value();
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I have not used the MVC Kendo functionality, only the Web version - but I am pretty sure that the normal MVC DropDownListFor assigns the name of the field so it binds correctly. In Kendo you are manually assigning the name (statusDropDownList). Can you not remove this line and let Kendo name it so binding will be handled automatically?

Comment: I added a change event and the selected value is being properly selected within the js function after getting a reference to the dropdown list. However, how can I place this selected value in the model when I post? If I use the regular DropDownListFor (not Kendo), this whole process works fine.

Comment: When I try and post, both the StatusID and Description are null in my Controller when I look at the Status model (stat variable) as below: public ActionResult AddSingleStatus(Status stat)

Comment: Trying removing this line: .Name("statusDropDownList")

Comment: If I remove that name, how am I going to get a reference to it in the dropdownlist_change function?

Comment: There is something I'm missing with how to pass the selected value that was changed back to the Controller. I wish more people would take a look at this to see what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Ok then try changing the name to match your model exactly: .Name("StatusID")

Comment: Why are you trying to even bind to the changed event? The currently selected drop down item, upon clicking submit, will be posted to the controller. If you DO need to grab that value with Javascript for some reason, then for model binding to STILL work you have to name the element the exact same as the model (otherwise how could it bind ?). Meaning if you name a model element MyModelElement, then in HTML you create the element with name myAwesomeModelElement, it cannot bind.

Comment: I don't actually need to bind to the changed event. However, I wanted to see if the new value was actually being selected when I changed it via the dropdownlist. I will try and change the name from "statusDropDownList" to StatusID and let you know. Thx...